# custom object multiple creation

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom, object, visual

I have a visual page that create a custom object with :

```
 public JSONDeserialize (ApexPages.StandardSetController con) {
control = new AKTARUS__c();

}
    at =[select account.ID from account where name='u47'];
    control.Name ='tessst';
    control.Type_of_alert__c='testes';
    control.Account__c = at.id;
    insert control;
```

It work once, but as soon as I try it again , only one object get created in the acocunt u47.
Even if I change the name and type of alert.

How come ?

Comment: Can you show full code

Comment: 2000 lines of code but i added the interesting part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`control = new AKTARUS__c();` - control is being initialised only in constructor.

When you are running the logic to insert (i assume its different in method as its not clear from question), it gets created. But when you run the same insert logic again, `control` is not re-initialised and so it points to older object which is already created and hence has Id, and so it will not be created. Try adding `control = new AKTARUS__c();` in same method in starting where you are inserting the object `control`.

```
control = new AKTARUS__c();
at =[select account.ID from account where name='u47'];
control.Name ='tessst';
control.Type_of_alert__c='testes';
control.Account__c = at.id;
insert control;
```

Comment: That is working perfectly . Thank you. Last small question , do you know how to replace the where name = 'u47' by the current account from which I am clicking to get the function Running ? In order to add it to my custom object @salesforcesas

Comment: SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and expressions if they’re preceded by a colon (:). Reference. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm

Comment: Yes but I have a button that call a vf page, that has a controller in which I insert my object. The goal is to get the account from which I am clicking on my button, so not with a semi colon and then the variable. But probably something like currentpage.get.ID

Comment: That would be difficult to answer here as I am not sure what and how you are displaying account and Wer is button and how are you handling click. If you can create separate question then someone can help